# Function to group continuous variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I'm trying to make a function to group variables in a data.table in R, and this is my attempt so far:

```
fun_group = function(data,col_a,lower,upper,by){
  data2 <- data.table(data)

  data2[, .SD, .SDcols = c(col_a)]

  #function to make categories:
  fun_cat_var <- function(x, lower = 0, upper, by = 10,
                          sep = "-", above.char = "") {

    x[x<lower] <- lower

    labs <- c(paste(seq(lower, upper - by, by = by)),
              paste(upper, above.char, sep = ""))

    cut(floor(x), breaks = c(seq(lower, upper, by = by), Inf),
        right = FALSE, labels = labs)
  }


  data2[, ("grp") := lapply(.SD, fun_cat_var), .SDcols = c(predictor,lower,upper,by)]
}
```

Problem is I'm not sure how the syntax works, where should I put the lower,upper and by arguments? This function gives me the error:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.table`(data2, , `:=`(("grp"), lapply(.SD, fun_cat_var)),  : 
>   Some items of .SDcols are not column names: [100, 200, 10]
> ```

, when I run

```
fun_group(mtcars,"hp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Are u looking for:

```
fun_group = function(data, col_a, lower, upper, by){
    data2 <- data.table(data)

    #function to make categories:
    fun_cat_var <- function(x, lower = 0, upper, by = 10,
        sep = "-", above.char = "") {

        x[x<lower] <- lower

        labs <- c(paste(seq(lower, upper - by, by = by)),
            paste(upper, above.char, sep = ""))

        cut(floor(x), breaks = c(seq(lower, upper, by = by), Inf),
            right=FALSE, labels=labs)
    }

    data2[, paste0("OUT_", col_a) := lapply(.SD, fun_cat_var, lower=lower, upper=upper, by=by), .SDcols=col_a]
}
fun_group(mtcars, "hp", 0, 400, 100)
```

If it is, you might want to close the question as its just some syntax issues.

Comment: @Helen, you might want to delete the question. As it is just some syntax issue

Comment: Ok, thanks! But I get "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."